# How to use context-param defined in web.xml in dispatcher servlet?

Tags: spring, servlets, properties

I have a very small concern, to which I couldn't find an answer even after Googling for quite sometime.

**How do we use context-param defined in web.xml in the dispatcher servlet?**

In my web.xml, I have defined it like this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>root.path</param-name>
    <param-value>/root</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I can access it in my Java class using the below lines of code:

`String rootPath = sce.getServletContext().getInitParameter("root.path");`

However, I don't see a way to use this value in dispatcher servlet. I want to use a variable for /root in the below case than the value itself.

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="file:/root/main.properties" />
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I have a question here. What purpose does this context-param solve? Instead of this you can externalize this variable anywhere in the environment variable or else. Here, at one place you are declaring the variable and other place you are referring it. Both are internal places nothing like externalization.

Comment: I didn't find it very nice to resort to environment variable. I want to keep my properties file out of classpath for security reasons (for storing passwords etc), and would be referring to it in several places. So I am planning to define a context variable and use it in other config xmls.

Comment: I would like to give one more suggestion. You should keep value of "root.path" in a property file and then decide from where you want to pick it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="file:/#{contextParameters.root.path}/main.properties" />
```

This will create problem if we give name as "root.path", instead give name as "root_path"

Comment: Awesome! It worked like a charm. Nowhere did I see this kind of usage after hours of searching on the net. Thank you!